# Ansible - Use when condition in a playbook for roles

Tags: ansible

I am trying to add a **when** condition in my ansible-playbook. However, I am not able to figure out the exact syntax/method to do it because my roles are using additional parameters. Below mentioned is my playbook

```
---

- name: Deploying application code
  hosts: uat-aegis

  roles:
    - { role: roles/send_slack, slack_message_text: "*`Started : Deploying code for {{ module_name }} on {{ inventory_hostname }}`*"}
    - { role: roles/application_code_backup, backup_directory_name: "NAME", repo_directory: "/path/to/repo" }
    - { role: roles/application_copy_config, repo_directory: "/path/to/repo"}
    - { role: roles/application_git_pull, repo_url: "git@code.git", repo_directory: "/path/to/repo", branch_name: "BRANCH_NAME"}
    - { role: roles/application_pm2_restart, process_name: "NAME" }
    - { role: roles/send_slack, slack_message_text: "*`=== Completed : Deploying code for {{ module_name }} on {{ inventory_hostname }} ===`*"}
```

Here I need to execute **roles/application_copy_config** only when a certain variable value is true. This variable value is passed as --extra-vars while executing the ansible-playbook from Jenkins(Boolean value parameter in Execute Script). I have tried using the below piece of code but it does not work.

```
---

- name: Deploying application code
  hosts: uat-aegis

  roles:
    - { role: roles/send_slack, slack_message_text: "*`Started : Deploying code for {{ module_name }} on {{ inventory_hostname }}`*"}
    - { role: roles/application_code_backup, backup_directory_name: "NAME", repo_directory: "/path/to/repo" }
    - { role: roles/application_copy_config
      when: "copy_config=true", repo_directory: "/path/to/repo"}
    - { role: roles/application_git_pull, repo_url: "git@code.git", repo_directory: "/path/to/repo", branch_name: "BRANCH_NAME"}
    - { role: roles/application_pm2_restart, process_name: "NAME" }
    - { role: roles/send_slack, slack_message_text: "*`=== Completed : Deploying code for {{ module_name }} on {{ inventory_hostname }} ===`*"}
```

ansible-playbook command is as follows

```
ansible-playbook plays/deploy_application/code.yml --extra-vars "module_name=$MODULE_NAME config_copy_path=$CURRENT_PATH/ env=$ENVIRONMENT copy_config=$COPY_CONFIG"
```

Please help me to use the when condition in the ansible-playbook. This is required becuase I need to execute the role: roles/application_copy_config only when the variable value is true. I have used [this reference](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#applying-when-to-roles-imports-and-includes) for adding when condition in the role

Comment: `when: copy_config | bool` should do the job.

Comment: @Zeitounator I am not able to get the syntax right with using when in the role while I am also passing the value for the variable repo_directory. Can you update me with an answer with the entire ansible-playbook which I have mentioned?

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you could provide the exact error you are getting. And rather than posting your entire playbook, you could post a much shorter [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) simply reproducing your exact problem.

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks for the help, I was able to apply the condition using bool filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to apply the when condition for boolean values using bool filter as mentioned below

```
---

- name: Deploying application code
  hosts: uat-aegis

  roles:
    - { role: roles/send_slack, slack_message_text: "*`Started : Deploying code for {{ module_name }} on {{ inventory_hostname }}`*"}
    - { role: roles/application_code_backup, backup_directory_name: "NAME", repo_directory: "/path/to/repo", when: var1 | bool }
    - { role: roles/application_copy_config, repo_directory: "/path/to/repo"}
    - { role: roles/application_git_pull, repo_url: "git@code.git", repo_directory: "/path/to/repo", branch_name: "BRANCH_NAME", when: var2 | bool}
    - { role: roles/application_pm2_restart, process_name: "NAME", when: not var3 | bool }
    - { role: roles/send_slack, slack_message_text: "*`=== Completed : Deploying code for {{ module_name }} on {{ inventory_hostname }} ===`*"}
```

Use the below code to check true and false

```
when: var1 | bool ----> true
when: not var2 | bool ----> false
```

Comment: Interesting approach, thank you.

But the default way AFAIK to do that is include role in tasks section of play, or implement conditional the logic inside the role (since role is intended to encapsulate as much logic as possible).

Answer (score 8):

You can specify conditionals with different style:

```
- name: Deploying application code
  hosts: uat-aegis

  roles:
    - role: roles/application_code_backup
      vars:
        backup_directory_name: "NAME"
        repo_directory: "/path/to/repo"
      when: var1 | bool
```